# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified -Mongo Import

Tags: python

I want to import a large amounts of data using mongoimport (Anaconda -Windows platform).I built a mongoimport command and I used  subprocess.call to execute.

Here is my code

```
 # Build mongoimport command
 collection = cal_data[:cal_data.find(".")]
 #print collection
 working_directory = "/Users/"

 json_file = cal_data + ".json"
 #print json_file
 mongoimport_cmd = "mongoimport --db " + db_name + \
                  " --collection " + collection + \
                  " --file " + working_directory + json_file
 #print mongoimport_cmd 

 # Before importing, drop collection if it exists
  if collection in db.collection_names():
    print ("dropping collection")
    db[collection].drop()

 # Execute the command
 print ("Executing: " + mongoimport_cmd)
 subprocess.call(mongoimport_cmd.split())
```

---

Here is the error I get

### Executing: mongoimport --db osm --collection chattanooga --file /Users/chattanooga.osm.json

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     16 # Execute the command
     17 print ("Executing: " + mongoimport_cmd)
---> 18 subprocess.call(mongoimport_cmd.split())

C:\Users\MMedouani\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in call(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    558     retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    559     """
--> 560     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    561         try:
    562             return p.wait(timeout=timeout)

C:\Users\MMedouani\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in **init**(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds)
    948                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    949                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 950                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    951         except:
    952             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

C:\Users\MMedouani\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1218                                          env,
   1219                                          cwd,
-> 1220                                          startupinfo)
   1221             finally:
   1222                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: `/Users/chattanooga.osm.json`and Windows platform ?? Either that file doesn't exist or `mongoimport` is not added to PATH. Try `which mongoimport` and use it with fullpath

Comment: Thanks scope. The file does exist. Can you please provide more info on how to try which mongoimport - Thank you

Comment: Please, ignore `which mongoimport`, this is for unix, the best solution for you would be either to add mongo bin directory to `PATH` env variable, or switch directory with `os.chdir(mongoBinPath)` to mongo bin directory. That path depends where you installed mongo.

Comment: Still throwing up the same error :FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified